# Why textFieldShouldReturn is still working when i return false?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am hiding keyboard on return key pressed by implementing function `textFieldShouldReturn` and calling `resignFirstResponder()` inside this function. It works perfectly but when I return `false` in this function, still then keyboard is hiding. Now here I do not understand that what is use of returning `true` or `false` if keyboard is hiding in both case?

Comment: return yes and have added delegate in storyboard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The keyboard is being dismissed due to the call to `resignFirstResponder`. It has nothing at all to do with the return value of `textFieldShouldReturn`.

In my experience, the return value of `textFieldShouldReturn` almost has no use. In the vast majority of cases it makes no difference whether you return `true`, or `false`.

I return `false` in all my uses of `testFieldShouldReturn`. If you return `true` and your implementation of `textFieldShouldReturn` sets the first responder to a `UITextView`, the text view ends up getting the newline added to it. Returning `false` from `textFieldShouldReturn` ensures this won't happen. But this was based on experience with iOS 4 or 5 a few years ago. I don't know if that still happens with the latest versions of iOS.

Comment: Yeah!!..exactly..it makes no difference whether i return true or false.But this function is called when we press return key(if return true),then how resignFirstResponder is invoked when i return false????(doesn't call in case return false)

Comment: The `textFieldShouldReturn` method is called when the user taps the Return key no matter what code is inside of the method. It can be empty and return either `YES` or `NO` and it will be called. Period. It's never not called when the user taps Return. And if you do nothing in the method (other than return a value), then the keyboard does not go away. It will only go away if you call `resignFirstResponder` on the `textField` parameter. And if you call `resignFirstResponder`, the keyboard will go away whether you return `YES` or `NO`.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy..this is exactly what happens with my code!!

Answer (score 4):

The return value from `textFieldShouldReturn` answers a *different question*. If the text field has an action for the control event `editingDidEndOnExit`, *that* will cause the keyboard to dismiss *unless* `textFieldShouldReturn` is implemented to return `false`.

Comment: I tried both, cases, and I could not see the difference. `textFieldShouldReturn` containing `resignFirstResponder` seems to always trigger `editingDidEndOnExit`, wether `true` or `false` is returned by `textFieldShouldReturn `

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that wether **true** or **false**, the keyboard do dismiss, here is the code:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}
```

The keyboard do dismiss or not depends on "**textField.resignFirstResponder()**",
if you delete it, the keyboard does no longer dismiss, whether true or false.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I worked on Native iOS. Nearly 2 years. I've just picked up swift 5 and working through the forgotten and new parts right from the basics. Here's what i have observed.

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if searchTextField.text != "" {
        return true
    }
    searchTextField.placeholder = "Type Something"
    return false
}
```

Here when I press the return key without typing a single letter in it, Keyboard does not dismiss. Rather the placeholder text changes to notify user to type something. The magic of returning `false` from `textFieldShouldEndEditing`.

If I press the same return key after entering at the very least a single character, it simply dismisses the keyboard. Courtesy of returning a `true` from the same `textFieldShouldEndEditing`.

I also didn't observe any difference when I placed `textField.resignFirstResponder()` regardless if I return `true` or `false`.

Conclusion:
`true` dismisses the keyboard. `false` stops the keyboard from dismissiong.